Ajax data validation approach
I am working on a web app. Before saving, I want to be able to validate the data. One of the validations is a duplicate check.
I have a function called DupeCheck. It does a jQuery Ajax call which returns one of two values: "true" meaning it is a duplicate and "false" which is the opposite. I am running into the problem of synchronicity here. Since ajax is async, I can't just wait for the return value from the server and then return true or false depending on what the server says. I do not want to turn it into Synchronous Ajax (and I believe that is deprecated anyway).
In pseudo code, I would like it to work something like this:
function save(){
   if(validate()){
      //Call routine that sends data to server
   }else{
      //Show error messages and go back to edit
   }
}

function validate(){
   bIsValid = dupeCheck();
   //Additional checks here
   return bIsValid;
}

function dupeCheck(){
   $.ajax{
      url:blah\blah,
      success:function(data, status, jqXHR){
          //set a value based on data
      }
   }
   return value_based_on_data;
}

I know my dupeCheck code is wrong. I am just not sure how I can structure this to achieve what I want. Any thoughts appreciated.

you can use resolve function if you found any duplicate then you should put resolve(false)  inside success function otherwise resolve(true)
